# Narrowly cast low-order bytes in C++

Tags: c++, casting, narrowing, type-narrowing

I tried to cast an `int` to a `uint16_t` with the following code:

```
std::cout << static_cast<std::uint16_t>(65537) << std::endl;
```

The output was `1`. As far as I've got it, only the high-order bits got cast to the destination type. I'm not sure if this is implementation-defined (I used *clang*).

I wonder, is there an option to specify which bytes I want to get to the destination type when performing a narrowing conversion? Are there some casts to consider low-order bytes first?

Comment: *only the high-order bits got cast* what is the source of this knowledge? The code behaves like a simple math task: `= 65537 (mod 65536)`

Comment: It's unclear what you want, you might want use the bit shifting `>>`

Comment: "only the high-order bits got cast to the destination type."... No, the opposite of that happened.

Comment: This is why a question absolutely positively needs to say what the **desired** output is.  If you had tried to tell us what you thought you needed, you would have either (a) realized it also was `1`, or (b) given us the opportunity to point out that your "low order bits" mental model was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conversion to an unsigned type is done by reduction modulo 2<sup>N</sup>, where N is the number of bits in the destination type. This equates to keeping the N least significant bits of a 2's complement representation of the number in question.

If you want to keep some more significant bits instead, you'll want to do a right shift on the value before converting to the destination type.

```cpp
uint32_t input = 0x12345678;

uint16_t lower = static_cast<uint16_t>(input); // lower = 0x5678;
uint16_t upper = static_cast<uint16_t>(input >> 16); // upper = 0x1234
```

Be aware, however, that if you might have a negative value, you probably want to convert to an unsigned type of the same size first, then do the right shift on that result. Results of right shifting  a negative number can vary.

Comment: What about converting `double` to `uint16_t`? Will this work?

Comment: @Kaiyakha: Yes--the integer part of the double will be reduced modulo 65536.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Well, if nothing else, I at least made the same mistake consistently...